# Print a form from asp.net core 2.0 for customer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, pdf-generation, asp.net-core-2.0

We are searching for a solution for the following problem:

We gather some data on our website via an HTML form. This data shall be used for creating a form which in the end shall be printed and physically signed. The data is stored in an MSSQL database.
We don't know which is the best and easiest to implement approach. We thought about having a PDF template and replacing some tags with the values of the database, creating a custom view and print it with 3rd party software or even use an SSRS server.

The most important points are the following:

- easy to use for the user
- the user shall not be able to change the document after he downloaded it
- the document should not be stored on the server (we prefer to have the document created only in the RAM)
- if we have to use third party software it should be free of charge
- the implementation effort should be as little as possible

Kind regards

Comment: SSRS can be a bit of a nightmare formatting and creating a document, but it can be done and also force the export to PDF. 
ASP and JavaScript can be used to create a "word document", but how do you plan on securing the document so that it can't be modified?

Comment: For us it would be secure enough if it's a PDF maybe editing locked by a Password, but not necessary. I think creating a PDF via OpenOffice is the same Kind of nightmare like SSRS. Is it possible to create a Word-Document via ASP and save it as PDF?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can create a word document in asp but you would need something like the FDF toolkit (from Adobe) to export to PDF.

Comment: Ok, but we want a PDF automatically created, so the User is only able to download this PDF and print it afterwards. It would be ok to first create a Word Document, but we don't want the user to have this Word Document, so there should be a PDF generated from the Word Document.

Comment: Give this a go. I've found another StackOverflow post with a similar problem.

 https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20640/Creating-PDF-Documents-in-ASP-NET